# How can I CURL a remote file to a remote server

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I am able to upload a local file to a remote server using the command

```
curl -T abc.pom -uusername:password URL
```

But I am not able to upload a remote file to that URL. The command I am using is this

```
curl -T remote-file-url -uusername:password URL
```

Is it not possible to do this? Is downloading it and then uploading it again the only option here?

Comment: another option as you want to is to use scp..it has the option you want

Comment: There is no scp option. Its not my server. They have given only CURL option to upload.

Answer (score 4):

My approach:

```
TF=/tmp/temp && curl <REMOTE_FILE_URL> -o $TF && curl -T $TF <UPLOAD_URL> && rm -f $TF
```

It might be possible to pipe the content of file from 1st to 2nd cURL but then the second one has to prepare the HTML form-encoded body by itself. The -T is a shorthand for this - it creates the form and populates it directly:

```
curl <REMOTE_FILE_URL> | curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -d @- <UPLOAD_URL>
```

Comment: But the first approach is just downloading anf uploading. Isnt it?

Comment: Yes indeed. I posted it as it is safer as I do not have to worry about how the fields in the form are named or setting the mime type myself.

Answer (score -1):

You may curl directly from the remote host by sending a command through `ssh` to the destination host :

```
ssh user@destination_host 'curl -o destination_file_path remote_file_url'
```